# CNTK Output Feedback

Tags: python, integration, recurrent-neural-network, motion, cntk

I want to implement a **CNTK Network** that is able to **learn a linear motion model**. Similar to a Kalman Filter task the Network will receive measurement data from an accelerometer and should output a change in the current position.

dx = v_0 * dt + 1/2 * a * dt²

```
              _____                       __________
input:  a -> |     | -> dx          a -> |          | -> dx :output 
        v -> | NN  | -> dv               | v     dv | -> dv
        ^    |_____|     |               | ^      | |
        |                |               | |_LSTM_| |
        |__ cumsum(dv)___|               |__________|

                                        Desired Aproach
```

Training Data for dv and dx is available.

Since the network should learn model free I do not want to input any motion model. My problem is that **without memorizing the velocity** from the previous time step the **acceleration value is not directly linked to the position change**.

Or do I have to do something like this:

```
              _____                               _____
input:  a -> |     | -> dv -> cumsum(dv) -> v -> |     | -> dx
             | NN  |                             | NN  |
             |_____|                             |_____|
```

Unfortunately Tutorials and Examples do not contain a similar task. I think it has to work with a RNN, Elman or Jordan Network. But I am not able to implement that in **python** in CNTK. Has anyone done something similar before? I'm still a bit confused with dynamic and static axis and forward declaration.

Another formulation for my question would be: How to teach a network to **integrate or sum**.

Thanks for every comment or hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was not clear to me whether you want to be summing the dv or not, I will describe the case where you want v = cumsum(dv); you can easily replace that with a learnable function.  I'm assuming 3-d acceleration data.

```
hidden_dim = 100
tradeoff = 0.5

accel = C.sequence.input_variable(3)
dv = C.sequence.input_variable(3)
dx = C.sequence.input_variable(3)

predicted_dv = C.layers.Recurrence(C.layers.LSTM(3, hidden_dim))(accel)
predicted_v = C.layers.Recurrence(C.plus)(predicted_dv)
combined_inputs = C.splice(accel, predicted_v)
predicted_dx = C.layers.Recurrence(C.layers.LSTM(3, hidden_dim))(combined_inputs)

loss = C.squared_error(predicted_dx, dx) + tradeoff * C.squared_error(predicted_dv, dv)
```

I arbitrarily chose the LSTMs to have 100 dimensional internal representation of state but output 3 dimensional output. I also arbitrarily chose to way the error on dx twice as much as the error on dv. The cumulative sum is a simple recurrence with  `plus` as your "recurrent cell". You can change that to an LSTM if you want. To feed data, just provide a list of arrays of shape `(time_steps, 3)` where time_steps can be different for each array. If all time_steps are equal you can also feed a tensor of shape `(batch, time_steps, 3)`

Comment: This is what i was looking for. I did not realize that one could calculate the error at different points in the net. The C.plus operation does the job quite well. I will try to replace it with LSTM and see what happens.

At the moment I'm working only with 1D sequences, but i will upgrade to 3D.

Thank you very very much!